# MySQL Community 5.7 - Invalid default value (datetime field type)

Tags: mysql

I've just installed MySQL Community Server 5.7 and I am trying to create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `atcommandlog` (
  `atcommand_id` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `atcommand_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `account_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `char_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `char_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  `map` varchar(11) NOT NULL default '',
  `command` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`atcommand_id`),
  INDEX (`account_id`),
  INDEX (`char_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

This gives me the following error:

> #1067 - Invalid default value for 'atcommand_date'

This same query works fine on MySQL 5.6. Has the default datetime value been changed in MySQL 5.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This looks like more of a SQL mode issue than the char set. Strict
>   mode (and more specifically NO_ZERO_DATE which is part of strict mode)
>   usually sets off that error if the table was created with an all zero
>   default date before turning on strict.
>
> What we use (for similar modified date columns), is the '1970-01-01
>   00:00:01'.
>
> and on a slightly related note, we use timestamp for these columns
>   (and for created time too). Takes half the storage space, and is
>   faster access.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6171/invalid-default-value-for-datetime-when-changing-to-utf8-general-ci